# Is there a way to create a set of sets in Unreal Engine 5 blueprints?

Tags: unreal-blueprint

I have a set of variables that represent the different pieces involved in a chess game.  I would like to make a ply variable (a branch of moves) containing the entire board and each move made.  Is this possible in blueprints or do I need to start coding C++?

Answer (score 1):

Unreal containers (Set / `TSet<T>`, Array / `TArray<T>`, Map `TMap<T, T>`) don't support nesting directly in either Blueprint or C++.

However, it's possible to wrap a container in a struct, which will allow to effectively nest containers. To do that:

- Create a new struct (in Blueprint, you create a new Structure in Content Browser, in C++ you define a `USTRUCT`).
- In that struct, make a new variable of your inner container type (in the case of your question, a set of whatever).
- Wherever you need a nested container (in your case set of sets), make a new variable of type "set of this struct".

Then you can access the inner container: in BP, use "break struct" node, in C++ use `.` or `->`.